# Persistent insert to MySQL database running in a container from an R program running in the same or different container

Tags: mysql, r, docker

I need to run an R application that writes to a MySQL database, both running on a remote computing cluster where I have no administrator privileges and so cannot install MySQL locally. My thought was to put the R application in one container and run MySQL in a second container, where the database writes to an external volume in my filespace. Then, start both containers connected through a Docker network and let the R application interact with MySQL and write to my disk space on the cluster.

R code:

```
script_mysql <- function() {
  library( DBI )
  library( RMySQL )

  conn <- DBI::dbConnect( RMySQL::MySQL(),
                          user='root',
                          password='',
                          host="mysql1",
                          dbname='test' )
  
  query <- paste0( 'insert into test (value) values (5);')
  DBI::dbGetQuery( conn, query )

  print( "Connected" )

}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:latest

RUN mkdir /home/analysis

COPY script_mysql.R /home/analysis/

CMD R -e "source('/home/analysis/script_mysql.R')"
```

Builder my Docker application:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

Create my network:

```
docker network create my-net
```

Start the MySQL container:

```
docker run --name=mysql1 \
--mount type=bind,src=/etc/my_mysqlForDocker.cnf,dst=/etc/my.cnf \
--mount type=bind,src=/Users/<my_file_path>/mysql_docker,dst=/var/lib/mysql \
--network=my-net  -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

Start my R container:

```
docker run --network=my-net my_app
```

This runs. I can see where the MySQL files appear in the "mysql_docker" directory. I can see that R starts in its container, sources my file and exits without error. The problems are: 1) the files in the database directory do not appear to be updating (so nothing appears to be stored); 2) I don’t know how to connect to the database running in the container to see if anything is changing. I tried:

```
docker run -it --network my-net --rm mysql mysql  -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Can you `docker exec -it mysql1 mysql -u root` (instead of `docker run`) to run it in the running container?

Comment: Why not use `docker-compose` ?

Comment: Thank you, both! @r2evans "docker exec ..." gave me "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'". I tried various user names, adding a port number to the starting docker command, specifically setting a password in the starting docker command and modifying the config file, but kept getting the same problem.

Comment: @Max I have not used docker-compose and know little about it. How would that help things and is there any specific command I should use? Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by first following the advice of @r2evans and using the "docker exec ..." command and then getting past the "Access denied" error by adding "skip-grant-tables" after the "[mysqld]" line in /etc/my_mysqlForDocker.cnf file.